# How to solve the following browserify error?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, browserify

I'm new to using gulp and browserify. I'm trying to follow a tutorial online which uses browserify and gulp.

Following is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "progressive",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Practcing a Progressive Web App",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./index.js"
  },
  "author": "Indu Pillai",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.13",
    "gulp-concat-css": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.20",
    "gulp-webserver": "^0.8.8",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "sw-precache": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm install`, it gives me the following error:

```
npm WARN browserify-shim@2.0.10 requires a peer of browserify@>= 2.3.0 < 4 but none was installed.
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, I'm not good at npm stuff either. I didn't ask for browserify-shim in my package.json, but may be some of the packages I asked depends on it.

Thank You!

Comment: Try changing your browserify version to 2.3.0? it looks like it might be asking for a version between 2.3 and 4

Comment: Install the latest `browserify-shim` v3.8.14, it works with `browserify` v13 and higher.

Comment: let me try these two solutions and will let you know.

Comment: Yes, changing it to version 2.3.0 did the trick, thank you!

Comment: @Deckerz but one this is not digestible. How can version 2.3.0 is higher than version 13.1.0. What kind of version numbering is that? 
I use rails, and ruby gems version numbers are so descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem
and I solve it with the following:

If you use the windows you should

1. Download the :(Windows Binary.Zip)
   Then choose the correct architecture to your computer (32 or 64),
   make it active
2. Open Command Prompt as Administrator
3. Execute this on the command line: `npm install -g @angular/cli`